# Angularjs ng-table apply directive to dynamic header

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ngtable

I'm using the ng-table with dynamic headers.

I'm trying to add a jQuery colResize wrapper directive to my table.
My problem is that the directive kicks in long before the thead is in place so the colResize has no effect.

How do I invoke the directive in the proper time?

Here is the directive I have so far:

```
'use strict'

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('colresizewrapper', function ($compile) {
        return {
           // A = attribute, E = Element, C = Class and M = HTML Comment
           restrict:'A',
           //High priority means it will execute first
           priority: 5000,
           terminal: true,
           compile: function colResizeCompile(element, attrs) {
              $(element).colResizable();

              var compiled = $compile(element, null, 5000);
              return function (scope) {
                  compiled(scope);
              }
           }

       };
   });
```

And the header that I'm adding looks something like this:

```
   <table data-ng-table="mainTable" template-header="ng-table/headers">
       <tbody>
            <tr data-ng-repeat="item in items>
               ....
            </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>

   <script type="text/ng-template" id="ng-table/headers">
      <tr>
         <th>title</th>
      </tr>
   </script>
```

When the code runs the directive is fired right away but the bottom script takes some time to get into the dom.

Any help would by highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: why you need to invoke `compile` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me best way to apply jquery contols inside directive its via `link` function:

```
.directive('colresizewrapper', function ($compile) {
        return {
           // A = attribute, E = Element, C = Class and M = HTML Comment
           restrict:'A',
           //High priority means it will execute first
           priority: 5000,
           terminal: true,
           link: function (scope, element, attrs)  {

               scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                  //this place right after all angular processing
                  $(element).colResizable();   
               });

       };
   });
```

### Update

The working plunk [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iidMkaFlp3F35JHneU4x?p=preview)
the solution is using `$timeout` to initialize plugin

```
.directive('colresizewrapper', function ($compile,$timeout) {
        return {
           // A = attribute, E = Element, C = Class and M = HTML Comment
           restrict:'A',

           link: function (scope, element, attrs)  {

               scope.$evalAsync(function () {
                  //this place right after all angular processing
                 $timeout(function(){ $(element).colResizable();   },100);
               });

       }
   }});
```

### Update 2

In order to support data source changing, you have to track changes, and call  `$scope.tableParams.reload();` in `ngtable` param class:

```
 var data1 = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},

        var data2 = [{name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                    {name: "Enos", age: 34},
                    {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                    {name: "Jacob", age: 27}];
        $scope.data = $scope.data1;

        //changing dataset
        $scope.changeDataset = function () {
          $scope.data = $scope.data2;

          //reloading ngtable
          $scope.tableParams.reload();

        };               

        $scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: 1,            // show first page
            count: 10           // count per page
        }, {
            total: data.length, // length of data
            getData: function($defer, params) {
                //grab data
                var data=$scope.data;
                $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count()));
            }
        });
```

working [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/TIqTQM2jIqxQ770oOoJ8?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Kostia, thank you for your reply. I used the compile since I'm only starting with Angular and I'm still learning. I have tried your code and it's still not working. I'll try to create a plunker for that later.

Comment: plunk will be usefull,i will make it too if needed

Comment: tell me if  data reloading will crash plugin initialization

Comment: Wow, looks great, I'll add it into my application and let you know. I actually tried at one point to use the $timeout but I always had a feeling this is the wrong thing to do.

Comment: it's not always wrong thing,i think it's should be ok,cause of event processing scheme in angular,so basicly it must be work with any timeout value

Comment: i will try to make it work without  `$timeout` ,cause i agree that better to avoid using timer stuff